# macOS - Reading part of other app library code and disassembling it to get offset

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, assembly

My applications read other application memory in order to get pointer. I need firstly to read offset from static library to start working with application itself.

Some function in dylib contains offset to pointer "0x41b1110" - i know that this offset works when used manually, but i need to to read that with my application automatically without checking value manually, if i do simple read from memory from address SomeAddressX as uint64_t it get's ridiculous address which is not equal 0x41b1110. im pretty sure what i got is simply this instruction. Then i have tried read this as byte array, and this byte array was equal to byte array from plain binary at this address. Im wondering how to read simply "0x41b1110" not entire instruction? Do i need to disassembly byte code to x64 instruction and then parse it to get address, or is there smarter way ? Im not much experienced with asm.

```
SomeAddressX - rax, qword [ds:0x41b1110]
```

Adding Example byte code and instruction

```
lea        rax, qword [ds:0x1043740]
```

which gives

```
48 8D 05 6F D9 99 00
```

first three `48 8D 05` appears to be `lea rax, qword` but the other part `6F D9 99 00` is not looking like `01 04 37 40 (0x1043740)` ?

[image: example]

Comment: You need to read whatever's at a fixed address in an arbitrary binary? Or do you mean that you want to look up the address of a symbol in that binary?

Comment: Basically read value from fixed address in arbitrary binary, and i can do it easily, but result is byte array which contains instruction i have pasted. I need to extract "0x41b1110 " from that but i have no idea how.

Comment: can you show how that byte array looks? (byte values). You didn't paste any instruction BTW, only argument part of some.

Comment: added as requested, it's edited in main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's x64 and enforced PIC (position-independent code) code on OSX (doesn't allow non-PIC executables, as it is using [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

So that disassembly is hiding an important bit of information from you. The true nature of that instruction is revealed here (ba dum ts):

```
lea    rax,[rip+0x99d96f]
```

It's using current instruction pointer `rip` to relatively address it's data.

The `0x1043740` is result of `addressOfInstruction` + 7 + `0x99d96f`.

The `0x99d96f` part is clearly visible in the bytecode itself.

The +7 is instruction opcode size. Now I'm not 100% sure it's added too at that stage, so do your own math, as you know "addressOfInstruction".

And check out your debugger options, to see if you can switch between the friendly absolute memory display vs. true `rip+offset` disassembly.

Comment: Thank you for reply, indeed very interesting.. Appreciate your time to explain it.

It's true that 99d96f is clearly visible, math is also correct 
0x1043740 = addressOfInstruction + 0x99d96f + opcode size

But it seems it that case opcode is equal = 0x57
How to get valid opcode size?

Comment: By opcode size I mean the size of the whole byte array encoding that particular instruction. To get size of instruction on x86_64 -> I never did any disassembler myself (neither x86 or x64), but I think the opcodes design is so hairy after all those years, that you basically have to have reverse tables for most of it, with some ranges covered by simple formula. Check some disassembler source? But if you are interested into particular instruction in the binary, then you already know the size of the instruction (in your case 7 bytes long).

Comment: @Steven: Thinking about it, too lazy to check the x64 machine code, but if you are after those offsets, I think they are usually the last part of opcode. So if you decide somehow the four bytes at address `<adr>` form an offset, then you can calculate target as `<adr> + 4 + <offset>`, because next instruction starts very likely right after the offset last byte (<offset_adr>+4 == next instruction address == `rip` value during execution).